# Web.config rewrite rule not working in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, web-config

When I visit mycompany.com in any browser except chrome, it successfully redirects to https://www.mycompany.com. However in Chrome I just get a 404, ditto all chrome users.

In web.config I have this redirect rule

```
<rewrite>
  <rules configSource="">
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Which I think is what makes it work in other browsers.

I've tried adding a HTTP redirect dns record, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: Update: adding a 301 HTTP redirect record to DNS converted the 404 message to a security error. When I click through that, chrome gives the error "mycompany.com" didn't send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Comment: open an incognito tab and see if that works.

Comment: Wow incognito does work. What does that tell us ? (I honestly don't know!!) :)

Comment: It is because it is deleting cached content

Comment: I have turned my comment into an answer. If my solution worked for you, please click the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a incognito tab and verify that it is redirecting to the URL you want it to.

Close incognito tab

Clear Google Chrome cache

It should then redirect you without having to use incognito mode

Comment: Yes, thats worked - thank you. So my 301 is working (since it didn't work the first time I tried before the 301 was put in place), it was just cached in the browser. Am I right that this means any user who attempted to visit before the 301 was put in place will still be denied access, but everyone who visits after the 301 will get the page successfully ? thanks again

Comment: (and - is there something I can do in DNS to say to chrome - forget that cache?)

Comment: So the proper solution for anyone hitting this thread is to (a) add a 301 redirect in DNS which routes blank.mycompany.com to https: / /www.mycompany,com and then (b) clear chromes cache. Sadly I don't have a solution for anyone who's had web traffic hit the website before the 301 was put in place.

Answer (score 1):

i don't really have a explanation. I'm using this myself.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

they look very similar but I have not seen problems in redirection to https. Maybe its something else thats cauzing the 404?

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a try out of hours. I don't really understand this but the differences seem very small. redirecttype is different - found vs permanent, the url is different, and your url match is in brackets

Comment: I was able to add the brackets to the match url=  and that didn't make any difference, I'll try the rest later