# IIS Rewrite/Redirect Rules

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis, https, server

I have problem with my IIS 10 Web Server i've written the following rules:

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.bg$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.bg/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but they does not work for some reason. I Have installed URL Rewrite module.

I want to write rule so when I write domain.bg in the browser or http://domain.bg or www.domain.bg or http://www.domain.bg , all to be redirected to https://www.domain.bg. Am I on the right path?

Comment: Not sure whats wrong but you need 1 rule to redirect http to https. U can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49279475/7324631) as a working sample to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS

Comment: Actualy, that is not working as well. I am missing something and i dont know what ..

Comment: Do you see the url rewrite module under iis? are you sure its correctly installed?

Comment: Yes, and it is correctly installed. i have mainly problem when i enter "domain.bg" in my browser and it says this site can't be reached

Comment: it doesnt redirect http requests to the right place..

Comment: As i understand its maybe not a redirect issue but a site binding. Do you have a binding to domain.bg? Meaning can you even reach domain.bg without the redirect rules?

Comment: i have the following binding : 
Type - https | Hostname - (empty) |  Port - 443 | IP - * | Binding Info - (empty)

Comment: Add a binding for HTTP same settings but HTTP port 80 and you should be able to acces the site then and the rule should kick in to redirect to https

Comment: That worked out !!!